# Element not found in the cache... how to deal with this when I dont know if element is available when I check? c# webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, while-loop, webdriver

My test is submitting form and checking on the message state. But if that state is refreshing from "new" to "sent", from "sent" to "received", and selenium checks for the element, I receive the error:

> element not found in the cache

Perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up. How can I deal with this situation?

The code that I have now:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[value=Send]")).Click();
wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")));
string state1 = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")).Text;
while (state1 == "New")
{
    wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")));
    state1 = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")).Text;
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")));
string state2 = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")).Text;
while (state2 == "Sent")
{
    wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")));
    state2 = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")).Text; //Error line
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")));
string state3 = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")).Text;
Assert.IsTrue(state3.Contains("Received"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm), specifically `TextToBePresentInElementLocated`, for that

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[value=Send]")).Click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.Id("messageState"), "Sent"));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.Id("messageState"), "Received"));
```

This will wait up for 10 seconds for the element to contain "sent" and "Received".

Answer (score 1):

I would setup the waiter to skip the stale exception and get the text in a waiter:

```
// silence the stale exception
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));

// wait for text "New"
wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")).Text == "New");

// wait for text "Sent"
wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")).Text == "Sent");

// get the final text
string state3 = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("messageState")).Text);
Assert.IsTrue(state3.Contains("Received"));
```